# How does Q perform his Earth illusion?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-q

In "Death Wish," in an effort to try to convince Captain Janeway to rule in his favor during the trial, Q shows her the Earth outside of her window.

Is it stated anywhere how Q accomplishes this? Does Q bring Earth to the Delta Quadrant? Does Q bring *Voyager* to the Alpha Quadrant? Is the Earth merely an illusion?

[image]

Comment: Logically, if Earth and Voyager were brought together even briefly, somebody on Earth would've noticed. Unless Q made them not notice; he's omnipotent, after all.

Comment: Exactly. With Q, you can't count anything out. I didn't know if there was a word from the writers on this issue.

Comment: The point is not what he did or may have done to make Earth appear out the window; the point is that he briefly made her feel like she was home to (unsuccessfully) compel a decision in his favor.

Comment: Well, that's fine, Anthony, but I'm still curious what he actually did.

Comment: He may have done nothing. He was speaking on behalf of the Q Continuum. While Q COULD easily have moved Voyager or Earth or created an illusion, it's equally possible that he was simply a mouth piece and the rest of the Q did the heavy lifting

Comment: Well, of course. Q could have also threatened Nagilum or some other super heavyweight to assist him with the Earth illusion, but I think Q doing it himself is more likely.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/voy034.txt) is no help whatsoever.

> **Q1:** *The Continuum is prepared to do you a little favor... if we approve of your ruling. Look out the window.*
>
> She reacts, goes to the window.
>
> ANGLE (OPTICAL)
>   -HER P.O.V. Out the window... she can see Earth.
>
> JANEWAY CLOSE-UP
>   **JANEWAY:** (whispering) *That's... Earth.*
>
> **Q1:** *Now you see it. Now you don't.*
>
> She glances away, toward him, and when she looks back to the window.
>
> HER P.O.V.-NOTHING BUT STARS

---

Given that Q is essentially omnipotent, it's certainly possible that he took the Voyager to Earth but cloaked (no mention is made of its arrival and disappearance later in the show when Voyager makes contact with Earth).

It's also *possible* that he moved Earth to the Delta Quadrant, then erased the memories of Earth's entire population or that he copied the Earth molecule-for-molecule just for the effect, then banished it into nothingness. More than likely though, it was just an illusion of some sort. He's made those before.

[image]

Then again, this is someone whose plan to deal with an annoying planetoid was to change the gravitational constant of the *entire universe*.

Comment: To be fair the solution Geordi came up with for the planetoid sounds even sillier "we should just take the planetoid and push it partway into a space where the gravitational constant is already different"